# Magento - Manage Categories doesn't work

Tags: magento, categories

I have a magento store with various categories one inside another (subcategory). My problem is that when we enter in the admin to manage categories in the category tree on the left, the categories or subcategories don't appear. Only appear to creat the "new root category" but doesn't work... So.. it's impossible add or see the category/subcategory tree. Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'store view' drop down in the top left of the 'Manage Categories' page. I'd be clicking on all the views to see which one had the category tree in it.

If you still can't find the category tree then it might be a data problem with the category set up.

Can you give more information about the history:Did this all work and then one day the categories just disappeared? Have you been using bulk import tools? Does the front-end of your site function normally?

A screen shot might help.

Also please inspect the Magento and web-server error logs to see if there is any error information.